# Unable to identify element in flipcart site

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am trying to find the "Buy Now" element in the flipcart site.i have tried many times with various methods but i am getting either InvalidSelectorException or NoSuchElementException.
help me in locating the element.Here is my script

```
    WebDriver d=new FirefoxDriver();
    d.get("http://www.flipkart.com/books");
    d.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[href*='children']")).click();
    d.findElement(By.cssSelector("img[alt='children_2-5_Years']")).click();
    d.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[data-pid='9788184514414'>.list-unit>.gd-row>.gu9>.gd-row:eq(1)>.gu4>div:eq(4)>.btn-orange")).click();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can u tell me which book, u want to select? If it is fine for u using XPATH, i can help you.

Comment: my goal is to click on the Buy Now button given corresponding to the book.by using this selector d.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Buy Now']")) the first Buy now button in the page is getting clicked.for ex if i want to buy the 4th book in the list i have to click the buy now btn given for that book.i am uable to find selector for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com/books");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Children")).click();//Click Children from left pane
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@title='children_2-5_Years']")).click();//Click 2-5 years old image link
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='products']/div/div[2]//input[@value='Buy Now']")).click();//click BuyNow for 2nd book
```

In the Above code, in the last statement, change the div number to click on different Buy now buttons.

Comment: Thanks for ur solution.d.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='products']/div/div[2]//input[@value='Buy Now']")) worked i am able to click on the btn  for a specific book.but the other two selectors are not working still getting InvalidSelectorException.could u please explain why

Comment: Updated the comment. If it is working fine, Accept the answer, So that it will be helpful to others.

Comment: it is working fine with xpath selector but not with the other two selectors

Answer (score 0):

Please use like  d.findElement(By.id("elementid")).click();

If selector does not work then you can easily use Id or xpath to get element.